# Is there a way to send to the server that the client workstation is locked?

Tags: citrix

I am working with an application that runs on a Citrix server. Is there a way for the server application to know that the client screen got locked? I don't want to use any additional dependencies on the client.

Comment: what do you mean the clients screen got locked?

Comment: I mean that the client workstation is locked.

Comment: You'd have to look at the citrix api

Comment: Thank you, but I already did. wfapi sdk only provides info about the session.

Comment: @dana then your requirements and what's possible don't fit.  If you can't get it from the Citrix server API; then you'll have to put something on the client yourself to tell you.

Comment: Then you are right, but this is what I wanted to avoid.